# Another PowerShell return issue

Tags: function, powershell, return

I've read some of the postings about Powershell and the return statement, but this script seems pretty straightforward to me:

```
function test ($n) {
    if($n -lt 0) {
        return "negative"
    }
    return "positive"
}
```

But when I execute it:

```
PS C:\Users\spadmin> test 5
positive
PS C:\Users\spadmin> test -3
positive
```

this output makes no sense.  In an effort to try and be even more clear, I changed the function to:

```
function test1 ($n) {
    if($n -lt 0) {
        return "negative"
    } else {
        return "positive"
    }
}
```

and I get the same results.  How do I get the function to return only the string "negative" for input values less than zero and "positive" from input values greater than or equal to zero?

Answer (score 3):

Try this;

```
function test ([int]$n) {
    if($n -lt 0) {
        return "negative"
    }
    return "positive"
}
```

Comment: OK, but the following works fine as main-line code with either a positive or negative value for $n:

`$n = 5
if($n -lt 0) { return "negative" } "positive"`


Why does a function need to know the type of the variable and the main-line code does not?

Comment: Compare: `'-1','0' | sort` and `-1, 0 | sort` - you pass parameters that are strings, and when comparing, PowerShell convert right to left. Reversing test would work too, compare: `0 -lt '-1'` and `'-1' -lt 0`

Answer (score 1):

Use a typed parameter:

```
function test([Int] $n) {
...
```